# How to clear the vue warn when I use vue-slider-component?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

The issue detail:
1. I implement the feature with the vue-slider-component module, but that has a lot of warnings when I move the dots on the slider.
2. I know that the reason is that I used v-for to point to an object that will change, but I do not know how to fix this issue.

the following link is my test site: 
https://jsfiddle.net/ncwv84x9/
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4Rjz.png)

My codes:
code1 (Html)

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="box" v-for="(item,index) in columnvalue">
    <label>{{item.text}}</label>
    <input v-model="value[index]" />
  </div>
  <hr />
  <br />
  <vue-slider v-model="value" :order="false" :tooltip="'always'" :process="false" :marks="marks" :width="600">
    <template slot="tooltip" slot-scope="{index}">
      <div>{{getText(index)}}</div>
    </template>
  </vue-slider>
</div>
```

JavaScript + Vue:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    VueSlider: window['vue-slider-component']
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      // collect the all values 
      columnvalue: [],
      // stored disease value
      pet_name: [{
          text: 'dog',
          index: 0
        },
        {
          text: 'cat',
          index: 1
        }
      ],
      // stored drug value
      feeder_name: [{
        text: 'Sam',
        index: 0
      }],
      // from age filter
      age: [
        65, 100
      ],
      test: "",
      value: [],
      process: dotsPos => [
        [dotsPos[0], dotsPos[1], {
          backgroundColor: 'pink'
        }],
        [dotsPos[1], dotsPos[2], {
          backgroundColor: 'blue'
        }],
        [dotsPos[2], dotsPos[3], {
          backgroundColor: 'black'
        }],
      ],
      after: {},
      relations: [],
      marks: {
        '0': {
          label: 'start',
          margin: '0 0 0 10px'
        },
        '100': {
          label: 'end',
          labelStyle: {
            left: '100%',
            margin: '0 0 0 10px',
            top: '50%',
            transform: 'translateY(-50%)'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  created: function() {
    //vue instance 被 constructor 建立後，在這裡完成 data binding
    let tmpArray = this.pet_name.concat(this.feeder_name);
    let tmpValueArray = [];
    for (i = 0; i < tmpArray.length; i++) {
      tmpArray[i].index = i;
      tmpValueArray.push(0);
    }
    this.columnvalue = tmpArray;
    this.value = tmpValueArray;
  },
  methods: {
    getText(index) {
      const ani = this.columnvalue.find((v) => v.index == index).text;
      this.after = {
        ...this.after,
        [ani]: this.value[index]
      }
      return ani;
    },
    getNodeRelation() {
      const indexs = this.after;
      let result = [];
      let result2 = [];
      let placement = [];
      for (obj in indexs) {
        placement.push([obj, indexs[obj]]);
      }
      placement.sort(function(a, b) {
        /* console.log(a[1]) */
        return a[1] - b[1];
      })
      for (i = 0; i < placement.length; i++) {
        if (i + 1 >= placement.length) {
          break;
        }
        let distance = placement[i + 1][1] - placement[i][1];
        let predicate = "";
        if (distance > 0) {
          predicate = "after";
        } else if (distance == 0 && placement[i + 1][1] == 0) {
          predicate = "hasUse";
        } else {
          predicate = "same";
        }
        let source = {
          label: placement[i][0],
          index: i
        };
        let target = {
          label: placement[i + 1][0],
          index: i
        };
        // store the 4-tuple reprsentations about slider        
        result2.push({
          source: source,
          target: target,
          type: predicate,
          days: distance
        });
      }
      /* this.relations = "{\"relation\":" + JSON.stringify(result2)+"}" */
      ;
      this.relations = JSON.stringify(result2);
    },
    getAllFilters() {
      let vm = this;
      let beginHas = true;
      if (vm.relations.length == 0) {
        vm.getNodeRelation();
        beginHas = false;
      }
      let result = {
        age: vm.age,
        disease_name: vm.disease_name,
        drug_name: vm.drug_name,
        relation: vm.relations
      };
      if (!beginHas) {
        vm.relations = [];
      }
      this.test = JSON.stringify(result);
    }
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I get a infinite loop error which disappears when I remove this section in getText()

```html
  this.after = {
        ...this.after,
        [ani]: this.value[index]
      }
```

This is because there is some reactivity triggered and re-renders the dom, which calls that function, which renders the dom and so on...

Comment: I solved the issue with your suggestion, thank you!!